# Handling Runtime View Binding errors MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, exception

I am trying to figure out a way wherein if an error occurs during the binding of a model to a view, I can simply redirect to a standard "A Catastrophic Error has occurred Page".

E.g.  Controller

```
SimpleController : Controller
{  
    ActionResult Index()
    return View();
}
```

E.g View. This is a simple view that just attempts to put the message in plain text

```
@ViewBag.Message
```

The above view at runtime will throw an exception as the dynamic Message Property was not set by the Controller. I get the Yellow and Red HTML screen (YellowScreenOfDeath??) with the code and error listed out.

What I want to be able to do is "Anytime such a runtime exception happens due to missing dynamic properties or null objects in my Razor file, I want the user to be directed to a generic catch all page.

Comment: You can do it like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6596694

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Your suggestion was helpful. I thought that handled only 505 / 404 erros