# How to re-route exception without marking Exception as handled

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, exception

Basically when my app has an unhandled exception I want it to be recorded as an unhandled exception by IIS (so that it can be seen on Event Viewer, for example) but I also want to route the user to an error controller.

I've overridden the `OnException` method of my controller in order to route users to a custom error page. The crux of the problem is this code:

```
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("GeneralError", "Error", new{ routeValueA = "some value", routeValueB = "some other value"});
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = false;
    }
```

My Problem is this: If I set `filterContext.ExceptionHandled = false` then I get a yellow screen of death instead of being rerouted to my error handling controller. If i set `filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true` then I get rerouted, but the exception is not recorded as an unhandled exception.

I know I can set a static error page using the web.config, but I **don't** want to do this, because then I can't use route values to dynamically send data to my Error Controller.

Can I succesfully set a result to my `filterContext.Result` without marking `filterContext.ExceptionHandled= true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try following from **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6339918/2065039)** source

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
    {
        return;
    }
    filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
    {
        ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx"
    };
    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
}
```

Or You can even try this too

set `custom errors` in `web.config` as below:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
  <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
  <error redirect="~/Error/UnauthorizedAccess" statusCode="403"/>
</customErrors>
```

Your **ErrorController**:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
    public ViewResult NotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;  //you may want to set this to 200
        return View("NotFound");
    }
    public ViewResult UnauthorizedAccess()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;  //you may want to set this to 200
        return View("UnauthorizedAccess");
    }
}
```

Register `HandleErrorAttribute` as a global action filter in the `FilterConfig` class as follows:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
     filters.Add(new CustomHandleErrorAttribute());
     filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

**UPDATE**

I suggest you to read **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16432718/2065039)** as it gives the complete detail to the question you have asked and I hope you will find a good solution there!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't solve my problem: I'd like to redirect dynamically (i.e. not with web.config), but also have the exception marked as not handled - so that IIS picks it up as an unhandled exception. I've edited the question to make it a little clearer

Comment: @ChrisRedhead.. Check the **Updated** part.. :)

Comment: Thanks for that. It seems to me that it's not possible to do what I want to do - i.e. essentially handle an exception but let IIS think it's unhandled - but I can't find a definitive source to confirm. I'll leave this open for a day or two to see if anybody has one, then I'll accept this as the most helpful answer.

Comment: Great @ChrisRedhead.. In the mean time I'll try to fetch any possible solution to your problem if available.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is Custom Error Pages that you can set in your web.config file and tell IIS to redirect to a custom error page instead of the default (as you called it yellow page of death :) ) for any unhandled exceptions.

This might help :
[How to make custom error pages work in ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905164/how-to-make-custom-error-pages-work-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't solve my problem. I want to be able to handle exceptions dynamically, but still have the exception marked as unhandled. I've updated the question to make it clearer